# Manage Python Multiprocessing with MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to run my code with a multiprocessing function but mongo keep returning

> "MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient with
>   connect=False, or create client after forking."

I really doesn't understand how i can adapt my code to this.
Basically the structure is:

```
db = MongoClient().database
db.authenticate('user', 'password', mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1')
collectionW = db['words']
collectionT = db['sinMemo']
collectionL = db['sinLogic']


def findW(word):
    rows = collectionw.find({"word": word})
    ind = 0
    for row in rows:
        ind += 1
        id = row["_id"]

    if ind == 0:
        a = ind
    else:
        a = id
    return a



def trainAI(stri):
...
      if findW(word) == 0:

                _id = db['words'].insert(
                    {"_id": getNextSequence(db.counters, "nodeid"), "word": word})
                story = _id
            else:
                story = findW(word)
...


def train(index):
    # searching progress
    progFile = "./train/progress{0}.txt".format(index)
    trainFile = "./train/small_file_{0}".format(index)
    if os.path.exists(progFile):
        f = open(progFile, "r")
        ind = f.read().strip()
        if ind != "":

            pprint(ind)
            i = int(ind)
        else:
            pprint("No progress saved or progress lost!")
            i = 0
        f.close()

    else:
        i = 0
    #get the number of line of the file    
    rangeC = rawbigcount(trainFile)

    #fix unicode
    non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
    files = io.open(trainFile, "r", encoding="utf8")
    str1 = ""
    str2 = ""

    filex = open(progFile, "w")

    with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=rangeC) as bar:
        for line in files:
            line = line.replace("\n", "")
            if i % 2 == 0:
                str1 = line.translate(non_bmp_map)
            else:
                str2 = line.translate(non_bmp_map)

            bar.update(i)
            trainAI(str1 + " " + str2)
            filex.seek(0)
            filex.truncate()
            filex.write(str(i))
            i += 1

#multiprocessing function

maxProcess = 3

def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    train(i + 1)
    l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(maxProcess):
        pprint("start " + str(num))
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

This code is made for reading 4 different file in 4 different process and at the same time insert the data in the database.
I copied only part of the code for make you understand the structure of it.

I've tried to add connect=False to this code but nothing...

```
  db = MongoClient(connect=False).database
  db.authenticate('user', 'password', mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1')
  collectionW = db['words']
  collectionT = db['sinMemo']
  collectionL = db['sinLogic']
```

then i've tried to move it in the f function (right before train() but what i get is that the program doesn't find collectionW,collectionT and collectionL.

I'm not very expert of python or mongodb so i hope that this is not a silly question.

The code is running under Ubuntu 16.04.2 with python 2.7.12

Comment: This is not exactly a new topic, as the general concept of "thread safety" with database connections has been around for a very long time. Probably why the error message is so descriptive and exact. You are being told to only establish a connection **after you fork**, so that connections live in worker processes **only**. If you want some type of **IPC** then you use something else to do that. But database handles being copied between processes/threads is "right out", and has been for a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

db.authenticate  will have to connect to mongo server and it will try to make a connection. So, even though connect=False is being used, db.authenticate will require a connection to be open. 
Why don't you create the mongo client instance after fork? That's look like the easiest solution.

Comment: But exactly how can i do that? That's the point that i don't understand

Comment: You may create the mongo client in the target function f. Or put the code for creating the mongo client in a function which f will call.

Comment: I've already did that but ,as I wrote in the question , then i don't know how to deal with the functions that require the variable collectionW,collectionT and collectionL.

Answer (score 0):

Since `db.authenticate` must open the MongoClient and connect to the server, it creates connections which won't work in the forked subprocess. Hence, the error message. Try this instead:

```
db = MongoClient('mongodb://user:password@localhost', connect=False).database
```

Also, delete the Lock `l`. Acquiring a lock in one subprocess has no effect on other subprocesses.

Comment: He has created the lock from the main process. So, it will synchronize the subprocesses. But synchronizing the subprocesses doesn't look like proper thing to do here, as it is working as a kind of big lock and defeating the purpose of using subprocess.

Comment: Acquiring a lock in one subprocess has no effect on other subprocesses. =)

Comment: Actually multiprocessing Lock (not the Lock exposed by threading)  is backed by semaphores (https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Modules/_multiprocessing) and hence they may be used to synchronize different processes. So, acquiring a multiprocessing lock will affect the other processes if they are also trying to acquire the same lock. Here is a gist demoing the same https://gist.github.com/nipuntalukdar/5562d5efd6970495e7632399057d5e99

Comment: Oh, assuming the questioner is using a multiprocessing Lock, then you're right, it has an effect, and that defeats the purpose of using subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it for my problem:

```
import pathos.pools as pp
import time
import db_access

class MultiprocessingTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test_mp(self):
        data = [[form,'form_number','client_id'] for form in range(5000)]

        pool = pp.ProcessPool(4)
        pool.map(db_access.insertData, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    time_i = time.time()

    mp = MultiprocessingTest()
    mp.test_mp()

    time_f = time.time()

    print 'Time Taken: ', time_f - time_i
```

Here is db_access.py:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def insertData(form):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client['TEST_001']
    db.initialization.insert({
        "form": form[0],
        "form_number": form[1],
        "client_id": form[2]
    })
```

This is happening to your code because you are initiating MongoCLient() once for all the sub-processes. MongoClient is not fork safe. So, initiating inside each function works and let me know if there are other solutions.